# A basic question on weak convergence of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $f_n, f$ be bounded and continuous functions.

Given that $$\int f d\mu_n \to \int f d\mu$$

for every bounded and continuous function $f$

under what conition

$$\int f_n d\mu_n \to \int f d\mu$$ is true ?

Is pointwise convergence $f_n \to f$ enough or we need uniform convergence ?

Comment: Pointwise convergence is not enough. Even for $\mu_n = \mu$ we cannot expect that $f_n \to f$ pointwise implies $\int f_n \, d\mu \to \int f \, d\mu$.

Comment: https://mathproblems123.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/variations-on-fatous-lemma-part-2/

Comment: You can see this blog for your answer

Answer (score 0):

$$\int f_n\; d\mu_n - \int f\; d\mu 
= \int (f_n - f) \; d\mu_n + \int f\; d\mu_n - \int f \; d\mu $$
 so given that $\int f\; d\mu_n \to \int f\; d\mu$, what you need is $\int (f_n - f)\; d\mu_n \to 0$.
Pointwise convergence is not enough, in general, because $\mu_n$ might have a lot of measure in a set where $|f_n - f|$ is not small.